# How to popup a virtual keyboard to enable user to fill out fields of an external page running in iframe on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ubuntu, iframe, virtual-keyboard

I have a web app running on Chrome on Ubuntu. My screen is a touch screen, and there is no keyboard available for the user.
I'm using my own JavaScript keyboard on each screen that needs input.
Now, I need to embed an external form in my app inside an iFrame. I have no control over this page's content.

My question is how can I provide a keyboard for my users to fill these iFrame fields?

I explored 2 options:

1. Trigger keyboard events - failed, since were deprecated mostly due to a security problem
2. Show chrome's virtual keyboard - couldn't find a way to control when it pops up, since I don't want it on my own pages.

Comment: you can give them acess to your pc using team viewer. i think that should work if you trust the person you are giving acess to.

Comment: The product is running on a kiosk located in a mall. The users are unknown, not registered. The solution should be a code within the web pages (JavaScript running in Chrome on Ubuntu OS).

Answer (score 1):

For anybody finding this years later like me:

There's actually **no** complete answer to this because there's a couple of problems.

You could actually add event listeners for both `focus/focusin` and `blur/focusout` to the document of said iFrame.
It works, but there's loads of pages with nested iFrames for login etc.
If you now try to add listeners to their documents too, CORS will block it.

That's actually a **good** thing because we could listen to keypress events as well and get passwords etc.

Now even if you deactivate CORS (which you of course should **not**), you would still need a MutationObserver as well, because many pages mutate the DOM to show inputs and whatever.
The Nodes would have to be *'scanned'* for inputs and iFrames too, and the documents of the iFrames too.

So you see it'll be a huge recursive mess, that's probably pretty bad for performance as well. Not to forget the vulnerability that comes with it.

That's why most Virtual Keyboard extensions, for example for Chrome, just don't work for said iFrames.

If you want to do it like them, you basically just have to define a whitelist for keyboard dependent input types, select the iFrame and do:

```
iFrame.contentWindow.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  if ((e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement &&
  WHITE_LIST.includes(e.target.type))
  || e.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement)) {
    //summon keyboard
  }
}, true);
```

For 'blur' (keyboard closing) you don't even need the conditional.